# Average function in Access 2007 returning strange results

Tags: sql, ms-access

In doing some database work I ran across a strange problem.  I'm trying to use the built-in average function in Access for a certain population.  When I run the query I get a different answer than when I look up the individual persons and then average the values.  Anyone notice anything in the SQL below that would lend itself to giving two different answers?

using avg function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachian, tblKentuckyCounties.Metro, Avg(Visits.admitNumUlcers) AS AvgOfadmitNumUlcers
FROM (tblKentuckyCounties INNER JOIN Person ON tblKentuckyCounties.ID = Person.County) INNER JOIN Visits ON Person.PersonID = Visits.PersonID
GROUP BY tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachian, tblKentuckyCounties.Metro
HAVING (((tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachian)=No) AND ((tblKentuckyCounties.Metro)=No))
```

;

looking up records individually:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachian, tblKentuckyCounties.Metro, Visits.admitNumUlcers, Person.PersonID
FROM (tblKentuckyCounties INNER JOIN Person ON tblKentuckyCounties.ID = Person.County) INNER JOIN Visits ON Person.PersonID = Visits.PersonID
GROUP BY tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachian, tblKentuckyCounties.Metro, Visits.admitNumUlcers, Person.PersonID
HAVING (((tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachian)=No) AND ((tblKentuckyCounties.Metro)=No));
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is pointless in those queries.  I'm not claiming it's creating problems, but suggest you get rid of it anyway.

Comment: @HansUp - you are right. DISTINCT (in the first query only) is part of the problem. See my answer below...

Comment: @Igor Turman That query groups by Appalachian and Metro, and produces a group average for admitNumUlcers.  In order for DISTINCT to make a difference, you would need to assume two groups with the same values for those 3 field expressions.  How can that possibly happen with the GROUP BY used in that query?

Comment: @HansUp - up-vote on your first comment is mine :)

Comment: @Igor Turman Thanks, I guess.  :-)  What I'm trying to say is GROUP BY returns distinct rows here all by itself.  Adding the keyword DISTINCT does not contribute anything ... because it doesn't change the result set.  So removing the keyword DISTINCT will not change anything either.  (I think that may be the point upon which you and I apparently disagree.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible explanation for the difference you're seeing is this GROUP BY in the second query:

```
GROUP BY
    tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachian,
    tblKentuckyCounties.Metro,
    Visits.admitNumUlcers,
    Person.PersonID
```

Any rows with duplicates of those 4 fields would be rolled up into a single group.  Check by changing the field list for the second query:

```
SELECT 
    tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachian,
    tblKentuckyCounties.Metro,
    Visits.admitNumUlcers,
    Person.PersonID,
    Count(*) AS rows_in_group
```

If rows_in_group is > 1, you have at least part of the answer as to why the averages don't agree.

Comment: i knew some records were getting rolled into one, i just didn't know exactly where.  thanks, dude! :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't be sure because I don't know exactly what you are doing to calculate your average when you are "looking up records individually," but I believe this answer from @Dale Halliwell might apply:

> [**An average of average values will not return the same result as a single average over all values, unless all the groups averaged have the same number of items.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570340/ms-access-rounding-precision-with-group-by/1570426#1570426)

Comment: when i use the second query i copied and pasted into Excel and then used the average function.

Answer (score 1):

While what @mwolfe02 pointed out to makes sense, in your case, the problem is different. There are two issues with your FIRST query:

1. DISTINCT
2. GROUP BY

So, if you use the following query (instead of the first one) you will get matching results:

```
SELECT tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachian, tblKentuckyCounties.Metro, Visits.admitNumUlcers, Person.PersonID
FROM (tblKentuckyCounties INNER JOIN Person ON tblKentuckyCounties.ID = Person.County) INNER JOIN Visits ON Person.PersonID = Visits.PersonID
WHERE (((tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachian)="No") AND ((tblKentuckyCounties.Metro)="No"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact layout of your database it's a little difficult to be sure, but I have a sneaking suspicion that you may be getting duplicate `Person` records.  What happens if a user has more than one `visit`?  Then, because one of the queries requests *unique* `PersonId` records and the other does not, you're getting different record counts.
You're going to have to decide if you want the average over all visits, or only over one visit, or what (this is not stated explicitly in your question).
Your query as written feels a little... interesting?  Try this instead:

```
SELECT a.PersonId, AVG(b.admitNumUlcers)
FROM (Person as a
      INNER JOIN Visits as b
      ON b.PersonId = a.PersonId)
      INNER JOIN tblKentuckyCounties as c
      ON (c.ID = a.County
          AND c.Appalachian = No
          AND c.Metro = No) 
GROUP BY a.PersonId
```

Here's what's going on -
This query will get you the average number of ulcers per person, over all of their visits (where the person lives in a county that is not in the appalachians or in a metro area).
It assumes that `Appalachian` and `Metro` are boolean values (`true/false`, or apparently here, `yes/no`...) - If this is not the case, things may need to be modified.

Comment: FYI: You'll need parentheses to get a query with multiple joins to run in Jet/ACE (the Access db engine).

Comment: Added parenthesis.  Feels like a weird restriction - is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a copy to play with - I of course answered with my experience on DB2.

Comment: Generally I would, yes - however, I though that at least some of the stuff I did with DB2 should translate.  It's good to know what's wrong, though.